# ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies

Tags: python, windows, pip

I am upgrading all my pip packages using a package called pip-review.
Now I get these errors. How to solve them:

````
The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested six==1.16.0
    absl-py 0.13.0 depends on six
    bleach 3.3.1 depends on six>=1.9.0
    google-auth 1.33.0 depends on six>=1.9.0
    grpcio 1.38.1 depends on six>=1.5.2
    protobuf 3.17.3 depends on six>=1.9
    python-dateutil 2.8.2 depends on six>=1.5
    tensorflow 2.5.0 depends on six~=1.15.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies```


How can I resolve them?
````

Comment: `user requested six==1.16.0` and `tensorflow 2.5.0 depends on six~=1.15.0` aren't compatible. If you change your requirements to `six>=1.15.0,<1.17.0`, then pip will install 1.15.0, which is compatible with the rest of your requirements.

Comment: But the thing is, I am using pip-review. And It is all done manually.

Comment: Looking at the docs, it’s looks as if you could use the interactive flag and don’t upgrade six, or use a constraints file.